# How can I customize SVN revisions?

Tags: svn, tags, repository, repository-design

I would like to know how to customize revision numbering in SVN. I have a repository I am running on an Ubuntu machine. The entire thing is currently just incremental revisions: `Current revision 7`.

I want to be able to customize the entire thing with a version numbering system (such as r1.0.0) and tag certain items inside it with an additional version system.

For example:

```
../myproject
../myproject/file1
../myproject/file2
../myproject/firmware/firmware_file1.bin
../myproject/firmware/firmware_file2.bin
```

Everything in the `myproject` directory would be under a release version `(r1.0.0)`. And the firmware files would be a part of the main r1.0.0 release, but would also have their current fw version tagged. So if `firmware_file1` was version `5.6` for that product. It would have a tag of `v5.6`.

Does that make sense? I am new to SVN and have been reading documentation, but have not come across instructions on how to do this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not have revisions in svn be anything but incremental, but you don't need to. You need tags.

Check out:

- http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch04s06.html
- [How to properly create an SVN tag from trunk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851377/how-to-properly-create-a-svn-tag-from-trunk)

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if it is possible to create tags within a tag? How would I go about tracking the firmware versions within a revision tag?